# How to lock internet connexion, bluetooth and WIFI programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a parental control application, so I want to lock internet connexion, bluetooth and WIFI using one button programmatically.

Is there any one can help me to do that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for technical questions. Phrase your question along the lines of "Can I use API xyz to..." as at least a starting point so that people can gauge your existing knowledge and see how much you understand the area of Android you are working in. Incidentally I don't think that what you want to achieve is feasible as a third party application.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the bleow links and implement all your requirements under single button click

```
[Enable/Disable WiFi programatically][1]

[Enable/Disable Internet programatically][2]

[Enable/Disable Bluetooth programatically][3]
```